# sum by id array multidimensional

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created in this format

```
var = items = [];
$('#ClientList ul.list-items li').each(function () {
   items.push({
      id: $(this).attr('data-id'),
      name: $(this).attr('data-name'),
      price: $(this).attr('data-price'),
      amount: $(this).attr('data-amount')
    });
});
```

I want to add `amount` if the `id` is the same since there are several `ul.list-items li` and items are added according to the client's need.

Comment: Ok - can you describe what problem you are having with the `+` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this code to get sum by id array

```js
var items =
[ 
  { id: 1 , amount : 20},
  { id: 1 , amount : 30},
  { id: 2 , amount : 10},
  { id: 2,  amount : 15},
  { id: 3,  amount : 15}
];

var results = items.reduce(function(results, item) {
    (results[item.id] = results[item.id] || []).push(item);
    return results;
}, {});

let sumByIdList =[];

Object.keys(results).forEach(function(key) {
  let sum =results[key].reduce((a, b) => a + b.amount, 0);
  sumByIdList.push({id: key , sum : sum});   
});

console.log(sumByIdList);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the code served me, although in my little experience I had to add some more things, but it is already my job, I did not expect to have such a good result. Thank you

Comment: @JohanCesarParedesCordova you are most welcome. If you need any help please message me.